# An error occured in the blob cache. The exception message was 'The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)'

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, blob-cache

We hosted SharePoint 2016 Web Application on Internet when users access it in ULS logs i found below errors
GetFileFromUrl: FileNotFoundException when attempting get file Url /1-icon-152x152.png The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetMetadataForUrl(String bstrUrl, Int32 METADATAFLAGS, Guid& pgListId, Int32& plItemId, Int32& plType, Object& pvarFileOrFolder)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetMetadataForUrl(String bstrUrl, Int32 METADATAFLAGS, Guid& pgListId, Int32& plItemId, Int32& plType, Object& pvarFileOrFolder)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.GetListItem(String strUrl, Boolean bFields, String[] fields)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.CommonUtilities.GetCurrentFileVersionFromUrl(String url, SPWeb web)

In EventViewer - Error ID: 5538
An error occured in the blob cache.  The exception message was 'The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)'.

Answer (score 0):

Reset the cache by going to Site settings >> Site collection Object cache >> Reset object cache. Make sure to select "**Force all servers to flush their object cache**", this will regenerate the cache on the next visit to the page.

**Here is a similar case for your reference:**

- [blob cache issue on SharePoint 2019 on-prem: An error occured in the blob cache. The exception message was 'The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/143553/blob-cache-issue-on-sharepoint-2019-on-prem-an-err.html)

Comment: GetFileFromUrl: FileNotFoundException when attempting get file Url /1-icon-152x152.png The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetMetadataForUrl   Here why it show Png file not found and error from GetMetadataFor URL